# IOS Background Mode AddOperation Queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, afhttprequestoperation, afhttpclient

I want to send my files in background mode but when i switch to background uploading stops.But there is no problem while sending video.i sending video post method.However i send my images as string...

my way to start operation

```
  [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager].operationQueue addOperation:requestOperation];
```

initialize to post

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",API_URL,Upload_Image] parameters:paraDict error:nil];
```

Other Codes :

```
[requestOperation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    MAINPATCH
    double percentDone = (double)totalBytesWritten / (double)totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    NSLog(@"progress updated(percentDone) : %f", percentDone);
    progressView2.progress = percentDone;
    patchEND
}];
```

handling

```
    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Comment: If you want to do background work then then you'll have to switch AFURLSessionManager. AFHTTPRequestOperationManager is based on NSURLConnection which is paused when app goes to background.

Comment: well how can i send my image file as parameters to php?by using AFURLSessionManager